# How do I download all PDFs from a website using R/automate multiple downloads?

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to download all PDFs on the USAID DEC database. The page has multiple links that lead to separate pages with the PDF links. Is there any way to download these without having to manually open each webpage?

Comment: While an interesting problem, StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.As is, your question (Q) is a request for advice or tools or code and is off-topic. Look at other questoins about downloading PDFs, notice the OS and tools being used, and decide which would be best for you. Then if you can't solve your problem, post an [mcve] to describe where you are getting stuck and people will likely help you ....

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.